# ZF2 add Input Filter to Fieldset

Tags: validation, zend-framework2, fieldset

I need to add additional fields to a Fieldset to integrate a certain flexibility to a form I am creating in Zend Framework 2.

I want to realize this using a method in the main form.

It is no problem to append an input field to the Fieldset but the problem starts with Input Validation and Filtering. I have no idea how to implement a Filter for a Fieldset after it was added to the form and the getInputFilterSpecification section was parsed.

Here is my current approach, which sadly does not work:

```
public function addAdditionalField($data, $filterData = null) {
    $fieldset = $this->get('additional');
    $fieldset->addElement($data);

    if ($filterData !== null) {
        $factory = new InputFactory();
        $filter = $this->getInputFilter();

        var_dump($filter->add($factory->createInputFilter(array('additional' => $filterData))));
    }
}
```

Any thoughs on this issue?

Comment: Do you know about [`Zend\Form\Element\Collection`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.collections.html)? That should cover your question.

Comment: I already use collections but the point is that I need to manually add custom fields to the form defined by a mixture of inputs (API, database). Like a custom builder for a form inside of a fieldset. 

I just don't see how to manually add filters for elements contained by a fieldset

Comment: The thing is your collection / fieldset should contain all possible fields including their validators. Now if your configuration/api says "dont have element X" then you remove element and `setValidationGroup()` of that fieldset to all elements apart element X - you REMOVE Stuff that's not wanted, you don't add stuff

Comment: Okay, no problem if the list of elements and their count would be a set maximum - but there is none. Think of it as an automatic installation service for software and each software got different custom variables. I am just able to retrieve the variables from a given and set database, nothing more.

Comment: @TheReaper, Have you found solution to this?

Comment: @mrN sorry not that I could remember actually...

Comment: Boo, I've got a similar issue...

Answer (score 0):

For very similar task I used and configuration array. This example from login form:

src/Module/Form/LoginForm.php

```
if($this->moduleSettings['enablCaptchaOnLogin'] === TRUE)
{
   $captcha = new Element\Captcha('captcha');
   $captchaAdapter = new Captcha\Dumb();
   $captchaAdapter->setWordlen(7);
   $captcha->setCaptcha($captchaAdapter)
           ->setAttribute('title', 'Help to prevent SPAM');
   $this->add($captcha);
}
```

in / Module / view / module / login / index.phtml I used the has() function:

```
if ($form->has('captcha'))
    echo $this->formRow($form->get('captcha')) . PHP_EOL ;
```

I hope this will help. check http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.Form.Form.html